# adjust resolution on Ubuntu Server 10.04?

Tags: 10.04, server, graphics, display, resolution

Installed Ubuntu Server 10.04 on an old laptop and I noticed that the system is trying to show the CLI below my screen. This means that if I run a script or a program with a bunch of output, once it is done, I have to press return several times to bring the output to the point where I can actually see it on the screen. I also have to clear the screen to be able to see what I am typing at the current command prompt.

The laptop is an EliteGroup 536S with a native screen resolution of 1024 x 768

**How can I adjust the resolution for Ubuntu Server 10.04?**

**What file do I need to edit if editing a file is the solution?**

I've seen posts on how to change the resolution on the desktop version of Ubuntu but not the server version.

Comment: Please add your laptop model and its native resolution.

Comment: Are you also logged in through `ssh`, and using screen or byobu?

Comment: @JanC I'm just running it on the laptop looking at the laptops screen.

Answer (score 6):

You can add kernel parameter **vga=792** or so (depends on your monitor)

```
  VGA Resolution Codes for GRUB & Lilo
--- Depth --
Colors  bits  640x480  800×600  1024×768  1152×864 1280×1024  1600×1200
   256    8   vga=769  vga=771   vga=773   vga=353   vga=775    vga=796
 32000    ?   vga=784  vga=787   vga=790   vga= ?    vga=793    vga= ? 
 65000   16   vga=785  vga=788   vga=791   vga=355   vga=794    vga=798
 16.7M   24   vga=786  vga=789   vga=792   vga=795   vga=799
```

Comment: That looks like what I am looking for. How do I edit this 'kernel parameter'? (location)

Comment: While in GRUB menu, press "e", edit kernel line and press Ctrl-X. If you want make it permanent, edit /etc/default/grub and run sudo update-grub.

Comment: I tried that, but it only changes the screen resolution while grub is running. It does not change it once booting is done. I'm running Ubuntu 10.04 Server. How do I change the screen resolution so it applies at all times ? 

I'm running an Intel mini-ITX motherboard with built-in display adapter. It has a default resolution of 1920 x 1080 that matches my LCD, and that's the resolution I get once grub is done. I usually operate the server headless, so I don't know what resolution I get without a monitor connected. How do I determine that via remote login ?

Answer (score 1):

Both vga=xxx or Elric's link to benhaines.co.uk solution didn't work in my Virtualbox Ubuntu Server.

What works for me was found at:

http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1743535

I added "nomodeset vga=792" to grub.  Change the 792 to a number suitable for your screen size.