# Ubuntu Server 15 terminal resolution

Tags: server, grub2, virtualbox, display-resolution, windows-10

Running an Ubuntu Server 15.10 as a guest VirtualBox VM, on a Windows 10 host.

Default terminal resolution is too small and messy, and I want to maximize the terminal or at least get it to a bigger resolution.

I've tried to edit `/etc/default/grub` and `/etc/grub.d/00_header` according to the following:

1. [Proper way to change terminal resolution in Ubuntu Server 13.04?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/299975/proper-way-to-change-terminal-resolution-in-ubuntu-server-13-04)
2. [How do I increase console-mode resolution?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/18444/how-do-i-increase-console-mode-resolution)
3. [Maximum terminal resolution in ubuntu server virtual box guest](https://askubuntu.com/questions/456527/maximum-terminal-resolution-in-ubuntu-server-virtual-box-guest)
4. [Change Ubuntu Server 14.04 Screen Resolution](https://askubuntu.com/questions/662744/change-ubuntu-server-14-04-screen-resolution)
5. [adjust resolution on Ubuntu Server 10.04?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/13150/adjust-resolution-on-ubuntu-server-10-04)

grub resolution does respond and changes accordingly, but I don't really care for that - I want to change the terminal resolution.

I tried editing the `GRUB_GFXMODE` line according to the `vbeinfo`'s available resolutions. After running `update-grub` and `update-grub2` I got the following output:
[image: output from running update-grub command]

Ideas?

Comment: are you referring to terminal or shell? note that they are 2 different things

Comment: Do you mean the resolution of VirtualBox console of the VM?

Comment: Well @ostendali: terminal and shell both refer to software... I guess the best way I can explain it is by saying I want more space for the lines that appear on the terminal, in shell.
More "black screen" in the back - so a big amount of lines will display "good" and won't have to be "lowered" to the next line.

All of the above refer to when I'm using the Ubuntu Server console - not the grub.

TungTran: I guess that yes. That.

Comment: referring to software doesn't mean they are the same thing, again, pls be more specific next time. However, if you follow the steps on this forum here: https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=33214 you can set the resolution of your preference.

Comment: Yes @ostendali, they are not the same. I just wasn't sure which specifies my intentions best. Anyways - I followed the link you posted, which essentially utilizes the same methods I've tried before - and the only "new idea" I found was setting the color to 8 instead of 32 or 24, but that didn't work for me either. Thanks for the link, though.

Answer (score 4):

Full-screen resolution can be achieved on the VirtualBox server console terminal, but setting only the `GRUB_GFXMODE` in the `/etc/default/grub` is not enough. (It may be enough for the desktop version though...)

I downloaded and installed Ubuntu 15.10 x64 server installer to test this solution and it worked!

**Install hwinfo**

```
sudo apt-get install hwinfo -fy
```

**Got the supported mode using hwinfo**

```
sudo hwinfo --framebuffer | grep <desired resolution>
```

For me it was

```
sudo hwinfo --framebuffer | grep 1280x1024
```

and the output looked like follows.

```
  Mode 0x0306: 1280x1024 (+160), 4 bits
  Mode 0x0307: 1280x1024 (+1280), 8 bits
  Mode 0x0319: 1280x1024 (+2560), 15 bits
  Mode 0x031a: 1280x1024 (+2560), 16 bits
  Mode 0x031b: 1280x1024 (+3840), 24 bits
  Mode 0x0345: 1280x1024 (+5120), 24 bits
```

> Please note that it gave two mode values for 24 bit colour, but only
>   one of them was a valid value, the other one just didn't work. In this
>   case do as I did, try an other value from the list.

**Edit /etc/default/grub**

```
sudo nano /etc/default/grub
```

Uncomment the line starting with `#GRUB_GFXMODE`, add below it a new line for `GRUB_GFXPAYLOAD_LINUX`. Finally locate the line starting with  `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT` and add the chosen video mode from the previous hwinfo query.

Here is a sample fragment of my `/etc/default/grub` file.

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="video=0x0345"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""

# Uncomment to enable BadRAM filtering, modify to suit your needs
# This works with Linux (no patch required) and with any kernel that obtains
# the memory map information from GRUB (GNU Mach, kernel of FreeBSD ...)
#GRUB_BADRAM="0x01234567,0xfefefefe,0x89abcdef,0xefefefef"

# Uncomment to disable graphical terminal (grub-pc only)
#GRUB_TERMINAL=console

# The resolution used on graphical terminal
# note that you can use only modes which your graphic card supports via VBE
# you can see them in real GRUB with the command `vbeinfo'
GRUB_GFXMODE=1280x1024
GRUB_GFXPAYLOAD_LINUX=1280x1024
```

Save the file using CTRL+O, then exit pressing CTRL+X.

Now we can upgrade grub and reboot.

```
sudo update-grub && sudo reboot
```

After reboot you will have a terminal with your chosen/full screen resolution :)

Also tried it on Ubuntu 14.04 and 16.04 with success.

Comment: Well I don't that setup anymore, so I can't say I tried your suggestion... but I recall playing around with those parameters before and they didn't work for me. Thanks for the answer, though. I hope others can vote this up if it helps them :)

Comment: +1 Ever since Ubuntu Server 15.x, I've been having trouble changing my console resolution when running under VirtualBox and this now seems to be the only solution that works. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @LightBulb Thanks for noting, :) `vbeinfo` worked for 12.04, but I found rebooting inconvenient, the process itself cumbersome to do and also to document. Installing `hwinfo` and getting framebuffer information is easier and more elegant, an evolution of Linux that i find appealing.

Comment: IIRC, in Ubuntu 14.04 and earlier, it was enough to simply set desired resolution by changing `GRUB_GFXMODE` in `/etc/default/grub`. I don't know why but someone decided to change this and make it more complicated.

Answer (score 0):

1. Boot the Ubuntu VirtualBox and press <kbd>Shift</kbd> to get Grub2 menu.
2. Press <kbd>c</kbd> to bring Grub console
3. Run `vbeinfo` to get supported modes

   [image: grub2 vbeinfo - supported vesa BIOS modes]
4. Choose one and modify `/etc/default/grub`, example (Uncomment the line)

   ```
   GRUB_GFXMODE=1024x768x32
   ```
5. Update boot list

   ```
   sudo update-grub
   ```

Comment: Thanks for the answer @Sneetsher. Though this concept is already found in http://askubuntu.com/questions/456527/maximum-terminal-resolution-in-ubuntu-server-virtual-box-guest which I posted, I tried it again. Running `update-grub` had no effect but running `update-grub2` did change the resolution, but only when the grub menu shows up - when the machine's running, the resolution remains the same. I'll update the question and add the output I got from running `update-grub` and `update-grub2`, maybe it'll give some information regarding the problem

Comment: @dsblind , I will try to setup same test env, and let you know my results I'm using VirtualBox  5.0.10 r104061 GuestAdditions 5.0.2. Could you [edit] question and add VBox & its guest additions versions. also output of `vbeinfo`

Comment: This no longer works with Ubuntu Server 15.x and newer. Answer provided by @elbedoit seems to be the only one that really works.